# Illegal monitor state exception on notification in postexecute of async task

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-notifications

I am making an app which notifies whenever there is a change in data stored online. For this I am using alarmmanager/broadcastreceiver to check periodically for any changes using async task in the broadcast receiver. If there is any change, in the post execute part of the thread, i am starting a notification.
 ON the line of "nm.notify();" i get an InvocationTargetException using debugger the cause of the exception is "IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()"
Can someone shed some light on what is happening. Thanks in advance.

The code for OnPostExecute is:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    resultstr=result;
    SharedPreferences sp=context.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", 3);
    String oldresult=sp.getString("notification", "hello world");
    if (resultstr.equals("unable to connect to internet")){}else if(resultstr.equals("")){}else
    if (!oldresult.equals(resultstr)){
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Tax Tracker 2014",System.currentTimeMillis());
         final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                 FB.class);
         PendingIntent p = PendingIntent
                 .getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
         notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Tax Tracker 2014", "new info alert", p);
         nm.notify();
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sp.edit();
    edit.putString("notification", resultstr).commit();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ankit you are using wrong method, you need the `notify(id,notification)` method defined in `NotificationManager` but you are using `Object#notify()`.

I think you need this [NotificationManager#notify(int id, Notification notification)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)

```
public void notify (int id, Notification notification)
```

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification
>   with the same id has already been posted by your application and has
>   not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Parameters

```
id - An identifier for this notification unique within your application.
notification -  A Notification object describing what to show the user. Must not be null.
```

*Reason for exception, but this is not what you want to do I guess.*

You need to first hold the lock on `nm` before call to `notify()`, using the `synchronized(nm){nm.notify();}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock the monitor before calling wait() or notify() on it.

try putting it inside `synchronized(nm)` block.